# Generate random values in R with a defined correlation in a defined range

Tags: r, random, correlation, generated

For a science project, I am looking for a way to generate random data in a certain range (e.g. min=0, max=100000) with a certain correlation with another variable which already exists **in R**. The goal is to enrich the dataset a little so I can produce some more meaningful graphs (no worries, I am working with fictional data).

For example, I want to generate random values correlating with r=-.78 with the following data:

```
var1 <- rnorm(100, 50, 10)
```

I already came across some pretty good solutions (i.e. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/generate-a-random-variable-with-a-defined-correlation-to-an-existing-variable), but only get very small values, which I cannot transform so the make sense in the context of the other, original values.

Following the example:

```
var1 <- rnorm(100, 50, 10)
n     <- length(var1)                   
rho   <- -0.78                   
theta <- acos(rho)             
x1    <- var1      
x2    <- rnorm(n, 50, 50)      
X     <- cbind(x1, x2)         
Xctr  <- scale(X, center=TRUE, scale=FALSE)   

Id   <- diag(n)                               
Q    <- qr.Q(qr(Xctr[ , 1, drop=FALSE]))       
P    <- tcrossprod(Q)          # = Q Q'       
x2o  <- (Id-P) %*% Xctr[ , 2]                 
Xc2  <- cbind(Xctr[ , 1], x2o)                
Y    <- Xc2 %*% diag(1/sqrt(colSums(Xc2^2)))  
var2 <- Y[ , 2] + (1 / tan(theta)) * Y[ , 1]    
cor(var1, var2)
```

What I get for var2 are values ranging between -0.5 and 0.5. with a mean of 0. I would like to have much more distributed data, so I could simply transform it by adding 50 and have a quite simililar range compared to my first variable.

Does anyone of you know a way to generate this kind of - more or less -meaningful data?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can just use linear transformations. The `r`-value will remain the same

Comment: It seems that what you're doing is generate completely random data, and tweak it so the correlation is right. You could also do the opposite and generate noise on the source data, then amplify it to have the desired correlation, maybe you'd be closer to the original shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with `var1`, renamed to `A`, and using 10,000 points:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- rnorm(10000,50,10)  # Mean of 50
```

First convert values in `A` to have the new desired mean `50,000` and have an inverse relationship (ie subtract):

```
B <- 1e5 - (A*1e3) # Note that { mean(A) * 1000 = 50,000 }
```

This only results in `r = -1`. Add some noise to achieve the desired `r`:

```
B <- B + rnorm(10000,0,8.15e3) # Note this noise has mean = 0
                               # the amount of noise, 8.15e3, was found through parameter-search
```

This has your desired correlation:

```
cor(A,B)
[1] -0.7805972
```

View with:

```
plot(A,B)
```

**Caution**
Your `B` values might fall outside your range `0 100,000`. You might need to filter for values outside your range if you use a different seed or generate more numbers.

That said, the current range is fine:

```
range(B)
[1]  1668.733 95604.457
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really like your solution, the only thing I don't understand is, how you found the noise. You commented parameter-search, could you explain this to me?

Comment: I simply tried different values of `sd` until I achieved the `r` value you wanted. You could program a parameter-search operation by iterating through a sequence of values or gradient-search-like methods, but you might want to try to code it yourself first and post as separate question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thats exactly the hint I needed. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with the correlation and the marginal distribution (ie, shape) of the generated values, multiply the values (that fall between (-.5, +.5) by 100,000 and add 50,000.

```
> c(-0.5, 0.5) * 100000 + 50000
[1] 0e+00 1e+05
```

*edit*: this approach, or any thing else where 100,000 & 50,000 are exchanged for different numbers, will be an example of a 'linear transformation' recommended by @gregor-de-cillia.